# how to insert subcategory into parent category(All) in mysql?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I need to insert subcategory values  into parent category in mysql without using loop.do u guys have any efficient queries.(i am inserting subcatgories using csv file upload)

Comment: Wouldn't that be impossible for us to answer if you don't even give us the tables involved, and an example of the data? Please, be a lot more descriptive in your questions...

Comment: Please choose right answer to your old questions and accept it. Do some effort that helps SO be better. It'snot so hard.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Nested Set principle. Here is a really good article: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), which in principle also applies to other relational databases.